# Getting the scroll offset of panning content in a WinJS HTML5/JS Windows Store app?

Tags: javascript, css, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've set up some panning content based on the WinJS [HTML scrolling, panning and zooming sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Scrolling-panning-and-47d70d4c). I'd like an event listener for when the scroll position of my scrolling content changes.

However, since the scrolling functionality is added using CSS properties rather than specifying a `data-win-control`, it's hard to figure out if there's an object whose properties I can monitor to get updates when the scroll position changes. The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465310.aspx) seems to imply that there is no such object exposed to JS:

> The scroll control provides assistance to users for panning or scrolling a view. It is exposed to Windows Store app using JavaScript developers at design time through Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) only

I've been trying to listen for the `DOMAttrModified`
event on the div which contains the scroll content (with `-ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory` & `overflow-x: auto;` set), but it doesn't seem to fire when the scroll position changes.

Is there an event listener I can set up for notification when the scroll offset of panning content set up via CSS changes?

I've tried a few hacks (including adding JQuery to the project & using `.offset()`), but whatever method I use sees the positions of items unaffected by scroll offsets (the base state of the page, as it were).

Comment: I don't know this WinJS thing, but which element are you scrolling? Regular elements like div (and the window) trigger a `scroll` event when scrolled, and you can check their `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` properties.

Comment: Hey, I think that did it! Post that up as an answer and I can accept it ;)

Comment: Good to know it worked! Just added it as an answer, with some links to useful documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular elements like `<div>` (and the `window`) trigger a `scroll` event when scrolled, and their [`scrollTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollTop) and [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollLeft) properties will indicate the current scroll position on the x and y axes. Also useful are the [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight) and [`scrollWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollWidth) properties, which give you the width/height of the content (including the clipped parts).

Comment: Good answer. I just want to add that you can run your app in debug mode and then look at the DOM Explorer in Visual Studio and see what your controls become as native HTML elements. Most of them are made out of div elements. You can find the right div element and see what class it has on it (it will start with "win-") and then detect the scroll position and put your scroll events on that element. Good luck!